# Set a default value in a select dropdown using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I have one simple drop down here.
Here  by default I need to show `Tobias` as selected.How to do it?

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
<option selected="selected">Tobias</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
</script>

</body>
```

This is what am trying in my original code.

```
<select><option value="" selected="selected">{{data.LeaveType}}</option><option data-ng-repeat="data in leaveTypes" value="{{data.id}}">{{data.Name}}</option></select>
```

//Here `data.LeaveType` is other method(getting selected option from backend)
//`data in leaveTypes` -to load drop down data

Comment: Try `$scope.selectedName = 'Tobias'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think leaveTypes value you are using is of object type ,where you want to display name but select id, for these kind of scenarios use ngOptions instead of ngRepeat

and modify your select as below, I had assigned id 2 for Tobias

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName=2" ng-options="data.id as data.name for data in leaveTypes"></select>
```

Please check below plunker for demo

https://plnkr.co/edit/GWsXGohTr6jvG67CY00D?p=preview

Comment: yah I have tried as you said ..am getting drop down data but that selected option only is not coming:-( trying for more than 5hrs.

Comment: Can you please send your controller and html

Comment: I got selected option srinivas :-):-) based on that selected option am displaying balance count right.for that am hitting one more method and getting response also,but am unable to append that `response` in `available leaves` field because defaultly am getting `available leaves' from service  .

Comment: `<form id="row editLeaveDetails" ng-repeat="data in leaveDetails">
                    <div>
                        <label>Leave Type</label>
                        <select id="levType" ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName=data.LeavetypeId" ng-options="data.id as data.Name for data in leaveTypes" ng-blur="leaveBalance(selectedName)"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Availabe Leaves</label>
                        <input id="levTaken" ng-model="data.Balance">
                    </div>
                </form>`

Comment: I am getting response like this `$http(httpRequest).then(function (response) {
                                    $scope.noOfValues = response.data;
                                    $scope.balanceCount = $scope.noOfValues[0].balance_count;
                                })`

Answer (score 3):

Just set default value using ng-init

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName=='Tobias'" ng-options="x for x in names">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">     
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='Tobias'"
ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your array

Answer (score 1):

Set default value for your `ng-model` object with using `ng-value`

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-value="{{selectedName='Tobias'}}"
ng-options="x for x in names">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also default set `selectedName` in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedName = 'Tobias';
```

So in your view:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
```

*In my opinion*, it is cleaner than setting it the view with `ng-init`, in order to keep the logic in the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedName = 'Tobias';
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why its not working for my original code?what I did wrong `<select  ng-model="selectedName" selectedName="data.LeaveType"><option data-ng-repeat="data in leaveTypes" value="{{data.id}}">{{data.Name}}</option></select>`

Comment: @user7397787 Try to use `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your ng-model to the default value.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $scope.selectedName="Tobias";
});
```

**Working Plunker**:https://plnkr.co/edit/cVaX1VdwFqAh8MoanNJS?p=preview